# What is the building code in the Turkish region hit by the recent earthquake?

Tags: turkey

I [saw some pictures](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-64544998) of the destruction caused by the earthquake that it the Southern region of Turkey and part of Syria in February 2023. I noticed that some modern building collapsed while other buildings close by remained intact, they seem to be built in the same period. I imagine that the building standards are not very consistent, but was a [seismic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_code) mandatory? What are the minimal legal standards in the region?

I am not asking about Syria because I assume that enforcing any legal standard in the region is and was quite difficult.

Comment: There is an NPR article on it that appears to suggest the issue is with older buildings. https://www.npr.org/2023/02/07/1154816277/turkey-syria-earthquake-why-buildings-collapsed

Comment: In general, when earthquakes hit poorer countries and cause really high damages, there are questions not only about the building code, but also about the *enforcement* of said building code.  That was the case in Haiti, and Iran.  Concrete may not get enough rebar, or might have too much sand mixed in.  That said, by the numbers, that was a brutally powerful earthquake so I am not sure they did significantly worse than could be expected.  There was also an earthquake in Turkey a decade or so ago, IIRC, so it is possible to look at was investigations found then - this one is too early to call.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Turkey might not be as rich as the US, but I would not put it at the same level of Haiti. AFAIK Chile in the past few years had some very strong earthquakes, but a strong seismic code helped to contain the damage.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Yes that is possible, but before saying that I would like to know what rules were in place. Actually also when they were set up matters.

Comment: Keep in mind that the costs of enforcing seismic codes might be larger than the benefits. It's possible that having lax regulations was a rational decision even in hindsight.

Comment: The building code will be a highly technical document dozens maybe hundreds of pages long. What are you hoping to gain if someone would like it here?

Comment: @quarague did you read the question or only the title? Are there rules that mandate anti-seismic buildings? If yes when they were included in the building code?

Comment: @FluidCode I did but my point is that the building code will not just say 'make buildings earthquake proof' but rather say things about for example concrete thickness and composition and I'm not sure any non-expert could get anything useful out of that information.

Comment: The best way, and I suspect in many cases the only way, to upgrade an older inadequately constructed concrete building to more modern standards would be to condemn the building, chase everyone out, intentionally destroy the building, and finally rebuild from scratch. That's not cheap in any country.

Comment: @DavidHammen My question was about understanding the reason why so many modern building collapsed. You can see a lot of modern building in the pictures of the aftermath spread around many sources. I also saw references to modern building in some articles. Retrofitting older buildings is a different topic.

Answer (score 7):

News is starting to come out that it was less the building codes themselves than their [enforcement or lack thereof](https://www.bbc.com/news/64568826), sometimes even on new buildings.  *Technical details* about building codes don't really belong here, but enforcement and political will to tackle the problem is on topic.

> Stricter safety standards were also brought in following the 1999 earthquake around the city of Izmit, in the north-west of the country, in which 17,000 people died.
>
> The latest rules require structures in earthquake-prone regions to use high quality concrete reinforced with steel bars. Columns and beams must also be distributed to effectively absorb the impact of earthquakes.
>
> These laws, however, have been poorly enforced.
>
> "In part the problem is that there's very little retrofitting of existing buildings, but there's also very little enforcement of building standards on new builds," says Prof Alexander.
>
> ...
>
> The recent construction means it should have been built to the latest standards, updated in 2018, which require structures in earthquake-prone regions to use high-quality concrete reinforced with steel bars.

We have seen similar issues in countries with poor governance however.  It can sometimes be easier to bribe inspectors than do it right. Turkey's [Transparency International corruption](https://www.transparency.org/en/cpi/2021) rating is iffy and has been trending down.  And, similar questions were asked after the [1999 earthquake](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/inatl/daily/aug99/buildings21.htm).

The code was updated at least twice, in [2007/2017](https://www.thestar.com/news/world/2023/02/06/poor-building-infrastructure-in-turkey-set-the-stage-for-widespread-destruction-from-earthquake.html) (my local building code also has 10 year update cycles wrt earthquakes as risks are better understood and building engineering progresses):

> Turkish experts agree that new buildings’ constructed in compliance with 2007 and 2017 earthquake regulations reduced destruction relatively, but they highlight that the measures taken did not go far enough.

And bribes may not even have necessary either, as the government seems willing to consider compliance avoidance as a profit center.

> She explained that as part of the 2018 zoning amnesty, licences were given to buildings built before 2017 which may not have adhered to building codes or zoning, in return for a fee paid to the government. In Turkey, 13 million structures were legalized under this law.

Keep in mind before criticizing overmuch:  this earthquake was quite violent.  And it is quite costly to retrofit older existing buildings, so saying that it should be done in all cases is unrealistic.

Where I live there used to be quite a long list of complaints about the seismic readiness of schools, but the government has slowly been fixing them.  Older rental stock is quite vulnerable, but since housing is in short supply...

Also, not sure about earthquakes, but plenty of post-mortem on forest fires in the NorthWest/California shows that there is plenty of apparently-random variability on outcomes - one house might be left standing amidst a patch of razed identical houses.  Don't read too much into isolated pictures.

Last, but not least, earthquakes are hard to compare to each other.  We see a headline number - the magnitude.  But that is at a point location, where it happens, not necessarily where a city is located.  If we take hurricanes, no one is going to say *Oh, Hurricane Gabriella was 320 kph at peak (at one location) and look how well Miami withstood it.*  (fictitious example).  *They'll speak of winds at Miami*.

[Kobe, Japan in 1995 had 6.9 and 6000+ deaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Hanshin_earthquake) IIRC, which might compare badly to [Los Angeles, 6.7 in 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_Northridge_earthquake), 50 deaths.  But is it fair to say that Japan is 100x less well prepared to earthquakes than California?  Few would make that claim and it would take some more work to make meaningful comparisons.

That all said, Turkey's government under Erdogan is not exactly covering itself with glory on [*disaster response*](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/erdogan-faces-crescendo-criticism-over-quake-response-2023-02-08/) and maybe a comparison to Kobe *is* warranted, where Japan dithered needlessly (one Japanese military officer had to act on his own initiative to send in his troops, IIRC, when central command wasn't doing anything).

In fact, Reuters reports the same about Turkey:

> Nasuh Mahruki, founder of a search and rescue group active in response to the 1999 earthquake that killed 17,000, said the army did not act soon enough because Erdogan's government annulled a protocol enabling it to respond without instruction.

Comment: So the seismic rules were set 23/24 years ago. In the last 20 years they built frenetically, there are a lot of buildings that were supposed to be within the code. An interesting thing the Turkish authorities could do is a list of the buildings less than 20 years old that went down and a list of those that stood up. Then they could check which building companies made ones or the others.

Comment: Earthquake codes are, more or less, an attempt to **limit** how much damage an earthquake can cause to a specific structure. But if the earth moves enough even well enforced codes [cannot save structures from that much force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_T%C5%8Dhoku_earthquake_and_tsunami) `A report by the National Police Agency of Japan on 10 September 2018 listed 121,778 buildings as "total collapsed", with a further 280,926 buildings "half collapsed", and another 699,180 buildings "partially damaged".`

Comment: In other words, it's hard to say that poorly enforced codes were the cause of the structural failures

Comment: @Machavity building codes usually try to prevent *deaths*, allowing people to escape in the immediate aftermath. But it doesn't mean the building will actually remain usable.

Comment: Regarding the hypothetical hurricane with 320 kph (200 mph) winds, that's at the lower end of the proposed category 6 hurricane. Not much of Miami would be left. That said, most of the damage from a hurricane is from flooding rather than winds.  Windspeed alone does not tell the story. Regarding the earthquake, this was a shallow strike-slip fault with a huge magnitude 7.6 aftershock. Shallow = more damage than a deep one. Strike-slip = more damage than other kinds. Huge aftershock = more damage than one with limited small aftershocks. Earthquake magnitude alone does not tell the whole story.

Comment: @Machavity Most people can carefully stand on one empty soda can. Wiggle just a bit, however, and you'll get a phenomenon known as collapsing of columns. (Collapsing of columns is what did in the NYC buildings on 9/11.) Earthquakes wiggle **a lot**, particularly so with shallow strike-slip earthquakes. There was a lot of collapsing of columns due to the recent earthquake in Türkiye.

Comment: @DavidHammen I get that (I've lived through some major quakes myself). What most people forget is the vertical displacement. Even the best designed building is not designed to be heaved upwards by the earth and then and dropped. Most earthquake codes are designed almost entirely for horizontal displacement, which is easier to mitigate (within reason)

Comment: @Machavity Strike-slip quakes, which tend to have primarily horizontal displacement, apparently cause more damage than do dip-slip quakes of the same magnitude, which tend to have primarily vertical displacement. This recent earthquake in Türkiye was a strike-slip earthquake. They are not as easy to mitigate as you think. The reason they're targeted is because they cause more damage.

Comment: @Machavity Dip-slip earthquakes tend to be more focused than strike-slip quakes. While the place right above the focus jumps around in a dip-slip quake, the damage is isolated. Strike-slip quakes cause much more widespread damaging effects. This quake was near a triple junction, a place where three tectonic plates come together. There were aftershocks galore all along the plate boundaries, and one of those aftershocks was very large.

Comment: @DavidHammen So, maybe Miami wasn't the best example.  Or maybe it was - winds can be precisely measured and if flooding caused the damage, that can be factored in (wind-damaged buildings:  bad builders, flood-damaged:  bad zoning or city/state protection).  Your technical arguments about strike-slip quakes, even assuming you are an expert, are not easily graspable by people comparing this earthquake in Turkey to say one in Japan.  Neither would be the precise composition of the ground in the area - sediments liquefy and cause more damage than bedrock.  There are just many unobvious factors.

Comment: @JonathanReez: The earthquake in Japan was substantially stronger. On the same (Western) scale it was 9.0, while the one in Turkey 7.8 https://apnews.com/article/turkey-japan-earthquakes-4547c9e6d98bc8cfecd2fc0c99fa1a83 This is somewhat easy to confuse because the Japanese JMA scale tops at 7.

Comment: @JonathanReez: OTOH, far fewer people died in this Turkey earthquake compared to similar ones in Pakistan (2005) or China (1976) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_earthquakes So one can definitely do worse in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the construction codes were strict enough and it's enforcement that was the primary issue. According to [a recent article](https://www.sozcu.com.tr/2023/gundem/iste-hatayin-bina-yikilmayan-tek-ilcesi-can-kaybi-yok-7588207/) (Google Translated and edited):

> The earthquakes of magnitude 7.7 and 7.6 in Kahramanmaraş caused
> destruction in 10 provinces, resulting in thousands of buildings
> collapsing and thousands of people losing their lives. Despite this,
> it was discovered that not a single building in the Erzin district of
> Hatay was destroyed, and no one died due to the destruction. This
> district is 110 kilometers from Hatay and 20 kilometers from Osmaniye,
> where the earthquake caused great damage.
>
> The mayor of Erzin, Ökkeş Elmasoğlu, stated that there were no
> casualties in Erzin due to the earthquake, and that there were no
> injuries or buildings that were destroyed. He added that while there
> were 50-60 deaths in Iskenderun, Hatay, and Osmaniye, there were no
> deaths in Erzin due to the earthquake.
>
> Erzin Mayor Ökkeş Elmasoğlu said that although they were happy for
> their district, their joy was incomplete due to the deaths caused by
> the earthquake. He also described his own experience of the
> earthquake, saying that he and his family were shaken so hard that it
> was difficult to move and that the earthquake seemed to never end.
> After the shaking stopped, they left their house with the things they
> could grab and started walking around the district. He was relieved to
> find that there was no ruin in Erzin.
>
> Ökkeş Elmasoğlu, the mayor of Erzin, stated that he did not allow any
> illegal construction in the district during his time, and that he has
> a clear conscience about it. He also said that even though he could
> not stop illegal construction completely, he did his best to reduce
> it, and that he would not tolerate it and would take action if
> necessary, without mixing politics into it.
>
> The fact that no buildings were destroyed in Erzin district of Hatay
> during the earthquake reminded people of Tavsancil in Dilovasi
> district of Kocaeli, which was the only place that was not destroyed
> in the 17 August 1999 Gölcük earthquake. This was remarkable because
> the Gulf region was almost completely flattened by the earthquake, yet
> Tavsancil was not affected due to its zoning plan, even though it was
> located at the epicenter.

Another [source clarifies](https://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/district-suffers-no-loss-in-devastating-quakes-180815) that Erzin didn't have any high-rise buildings:

> The mayor also pointed out that the majority of the houses in the district are either detached or four-story, while the highest number of floors is six, which is very few.

The Erzin district is located 76km from the epicenter. Assuming the article is indeed correct about the lack of collapsed buildings in the district, it seems like lack of enforcement was the main culprit in many cases, at least when it comes to buildings with 6 floors or lower.

Comment: Sounds like a push answer to add the usual tirade against high rises.

Comment: @FluidCode I'm confused as to who is supposed to be against high rises? Myself? The mayor of Erzin? The journalists?

Comment: If you build according to the seismic code you can build a high rise that is able to withstand an earthquake and even a skyscraper. In a country plagued by overpopulation and indiscriminate city growth due to lack of urban planning the argument yes or no high rises is a good way to distract the attention from the substandard buildings and reduce the pressure on the government. So I would say that pushing the argument is in the interest of a lot of people.  BTW I noticed that the argument is being pushed also via Wikipedia, see the article about Erzin.

Comment: According to the map Erzin lies on a plain that is formed by a small sedimentary patch on the edge of the mountains. Furthermore it is about 100 Km from the epicentre of the second earthquake and even farther from the epicentre of the first. There might be other reasons why the town suffered no damage.

Comment: @FluidCode I’m not opposed to high rises personally. That being said, some of the densest neighborhoods in the world are actually in downtown Barcelona where all the buildings are less than 6 stories tall. They achieve the density by having narrow streets and relying on public transit.